# handling .find() failures in beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have a lot of fields that require multiple *.find()* calls example:

```
km1 = soup.find(id='milage').findChild(class_='c2').text.strip
km2 = soup.find(id='milage2').findChild(class_='c2').text.strip
speed = soup.find(id='speed').findChild(class_='c3').text.strip
```

now surrounding every one of them with try/catch is a bit silly and makes the whole thing unreadable, how could I make it that if it fails at any point it would return some sort of empty value?

Comment: Using `try/catch` is not silly if you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using `select` mehtod](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class), you can use css selector which is a lot easier to read/writer.

```
km1 = soup.select('#milage .c2')
kml = kml[0].text.strip() if kml else None
```

Comment: select returns a list which has no text, doesn't it? for that you would need to do km1 = soup.select('#milage .c2')[0].text.strip() which would cause IndexOutOfRange.

Comment: @Bernard, You're right. I updated the answer to use conditional expression to avoid the exception.

Comment: Thanks, I've used:
"".join([item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('#milage .c2')])
to compress it into one line, but it's essentially the same